# Controls in UIActionSheet are positioning wrong

Tags: objective-c, ipad, orientation, subview, uiactionsheet

I need to display a pop with a **UISwitch** and a Done button when user taps on a button and save the state of the switch when the done button in the pop up is tapped.

So I use **UIActionSheet** to do this -

```
sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Switch Setting" 
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];

theSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
[sheet addSubview:theSwitch];
[sheet showInView:self.view];


- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.firstOtherButtonIndex)
    {
      theSwitch .on? NSLog(@"Switch is on") : NSLog(@"Switch if off");
    }
}
```

All this works great. I have **problem with positioning**. Unfortunately, I don't have a screen shot at the moment to post here. But the switch appears at the very top on the same line with the Action Sheet title and then below that is the Done button.

Please someone help me how to position the switch below the Title and increase the Action Sheet size so it looks neat. I need this asap. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the frame of the switch.

To position the switch in the middle of the alert view

```
theSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
[sheet addSubview:theSwitch];
[sheet showInView:self.view];

// get the dimension of the sheet to position the switch
CGSize parentSize  = sheet.frame.size;
CGRect rect = theSwitch.frame;
rect.origin.x = parentSize.width/2.0 - rect.size.width;
rect.origin.y = parentSize.height - rect.size.height - <some space from the bottom>;
theSwitch.frame = rect;
```

It is important, that you position the switch after calling showInView for the sheet. Otherwise the size of the sheet is zero. If you replace  you can add same space to the bottom.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the option to do it by modifying frame of `UISwitch` like `trumi` described above. If you want to place a `UIButton` with image them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130475/adding-images-to-uiactionsheet-buttons-as-in-uidocumentinteractioncontroller) is a undocumented option. Undocumented, so risk of rejection.

Also you will find many other beautification option in the [same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9779533/362310)